# page redirection base on date/time

Tags: javascript

I need help with the javascript code.
If I want to redirect the browser to two different URLs during different times in the weekday, how do I do this in javascript:
if (Mon-Fri 8:00am-9:00pm, Sat 8:am-5pm )
window.location = URL1
else (M-F 8:59pm-7:59am, Sat-M 4:59pm-7:59am) 
window.location = URL2

TIA

Comment: Show us what you have tried, I can help you on a code example _but will not do all the work for you_.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started...

```
var date = new Date,
    day = date.getDay(),
    hour = date.getHours();


if ((day >= 1 && day <= 5 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 21) || (day == 6 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 17)) {
    window.location = 'a';
} else {
    window.location = 'b';
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nrqsm/).

Comment: Take note of the minutes as well. But yeah, OP should've given some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `Date` class to help you. Here's a [tutorial on it](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php). So use `new Date()` to construct a date with the current time, and then use its various methods to check if the time is in the ranges you want.

**EDIT**: Why do I always get ninja'd? :D